# How to log error messages into a file instead of browser in a react js application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, logging

I have tried going through log4js but do we need to create an api to store logs in log4js.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with Javascript, the simplest solution would probably be to write a little Node web server (using Express, for instance) that you could send errors to when they happen? The server could append them to a file as it receives them.